# Issues with Translucent Theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an app that has two activities.
The first one is presented with a single button that opens the second one.

Here is the Manifiest definition for the first one:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.buttonexample.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Second activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.buttonexample.MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
</activity>
```

Here is how I launch the second activity (via OnClickListener for a button on the first activity):

```
public void startSecondActivityClick(View v) {
   Intent startActivity2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
   startActivity(startActivity2);
}
```

This works fine, however when I background the app by hitting home and the foreground the app. I'm noticing that the first activity is continually creating/destroying itself. I verified this by putting some code in the onDestory method to increment a static int:

```
private static int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    count++;

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("MainActivity", String.format("Destroyed, %d", count));
}
```

I've also noticed that removing the translucent theme seems to fix this. My question is is there a way to translucent or something similar but also have it not restart? Also, I'm curious why this happens at all. I'm testing this on 4.0.1 ICS on a galaxy SIII.

Comment: What do you mean that it's continually creating and destroying itself? Do you mean that it's creating, and destroying multiple times when you view the second activity only once? Can you give us an example of the Log output?

Comment: I mean onCreate and onDestroy are being called in rapid succession. I will add some log output.

Comment: Ok after some digging I was able to figure out why this is happening. Someone had turned on one of the developer options, "do not keep activities.". After turning this off this stopped happening. I suspect this wouldn't happen in production too often as most people probably don't have that setting on.

Comment: Hi, out of curiosity, where can I tunr on this option to "do not keep activities"?

Comment: It's under "developer options" under settings. It may not be available on older versions of android.

Comment: @noahd you might want to move your comment about "developer options" to an answer.  Not everyone reads the comments and I know an answer like that I would have up-voted

Comment: Please answer this question and accept your own answer so it doesn't show up on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some digging I was able to figure out why this is happening. Someone had turned on one of the developer options, "do not keep activities.". After turning this off this stopped happening. I suspect this wouldn't happen in production too often as most people probably don't have that setting on. You can find this under settings -> "developer options" on most phones.